# SpecialFolder.MyDocuments giving correct value in a console application but not on a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, environment-variables

I have a windows service running on my machine. When I do a

```
 Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

it gives me empty string but when I do the same thing in a console application it gives me the correct location of my MyDocuments folder.

Any ideas as to why it might be happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is because when you run the application as a Console you are running signed in to the computer as you, the user, and can therefore access your "My Documents". When the Windows Service is running (by default) it will run as **Local System** which doesn't have a "My Documents" folder. This is because Windows Services run when the computer starts up and doesn't need a user signed in.

The question is, what are you trying to do with your "My Documents" folder and your Windows Service probably wants to access a location that is not user dependent?

Finally, to make it clear imagine if you had 10 users setup on the computer. Which user's "My Documents" would the Windows Service use when no-one has signed in yet?

Comment: This service is someone else's code. I think when he deploys it he changes the Log On user from services.msc. Stupid of me to ask this question I guess. But thanks !

Comment: Not stupid at all and often the user is changed for security reason but you need to decide what the service is doing and where it should be reading / writing and go from there.

Comment: Does local system always run on `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Documents` ? Any method that returns this path?