# How to allow Windows service to access file system?

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, windows-services

I have a C# console application running as a Windows service. How can I allow it to access the file system?

Should I create an account for it? If so, I don't think I want a user account. (I noticed that other Windows services are run under accounts that don't show up under my user accounts.) If this is the right approach, how do I create one of these type of accounts?

But whenever I Google this, I just seem to find pages for creating regular user accounts.

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you just use ```System.IO``` to access the file system? Does it require some kind of extra permission?

Comment: What do you mean by _"allow it to access the file system"_?

Comment: Your service does indeed need to run under an account that is granted access to the file system. I have a list of such accounts for use on our corporate work environment but I do not believe I have the proper access rights to create them myself - FWIW.

Comment: @ÖzgürGüzeldereli: That doesn't appear to work with Windows services by default.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Allow it to read and write files.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: I see there are a bunch of accounts. I have no idea what they do. I log in as Administrator, but not sure I want to run the service under that account.

Comment: Then just ... read and write files? Is this a theoretical question? Have you tried anything? What exactly are you looking for? What do you mean by _"doesn't appear to work with Windows services by default"_? Have you tried it? What happened? This isn't your first question, you know how this works.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I don't get your response. Obviously, I've tried writing to files but nothing is written. Obviously, I don't have permission. But I can't actually debug the code when it's running as a Windows service. If I run the Windows Service under my Admin account, it works. But I'm not sure that's a good idea. Thus, my question.

Comment: It is impossible that "nothing happens". Either a file gets written or you get an exception, or you actually didn't write. Please read [ask] and provide us with an [mre], that is, help us reproduce the issue. There's nothing special about Windows Services.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Someone who is familiar with creating and configuring Windows services would understand the question. Just as one of the people who commented understood exactly what my issue is. Windows services, by default, runs under an account that cannot access the file system. I don't need help with the part about working with files.

Comment: I have created, deployed and maintained dozens of Windows Services. This stuff isn't voodoo, it isn't special. If you have trouble recreating or even describing an issue, read [ask] and [mre]. When you create a Windows Service, you specify an account for it to run under. If you haven't created a user account and haven't specified an account for it, it'll run as the built-in account LocalSystem which is about the same as Administrator. Now try again and provide us with enough detail to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @CodeCaster: As I explained in my question, other services are run under accounts that do not show up in my user accounts. It appears to me that these are a different type of account. And I'm trying to figure out if I should create one of these types of accounts and, if so, how. And if I run across someone with deeper knowledge, they might even offer best practices on the matter. I don't know how to make it more clear than that.

Comment: @500 mentions accounts for usage a corporate network. You do not. If you want your service to access network shares, then yes, it should run as a user that has permissions to access those (or as NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, yet another built-in account, acting as the machine on the network). You didn't mention any of that. Just don't be so stubborn and mention explicitly what your code looks like, how your accounts are configured and what paths (local or remote) you're trying to access.

Comment: _Which_ other services? _Which_ accounts? [`LocalSystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localsystem-account) and [`Network Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/networkservice-account)? Those are built-in accounts that indeed do not show up as local user accounts. For the eight hundredth time: if you need help, you need to explain what you're trying to do and where you are stuck. You can't wait for someone who knows everything (including what's on your screen) to come along and answer a question you don't ask.

Comment: @CodeCaster: My code writes to a text file. And it will need to read from files, and also copy files. If we dig into my test code that writes to a file, then we are way far afield from my question. My app doesn't need to access a network (other than the Web). Just the file system.

Comment: Then show your code that writes to a text file. It either succeeds (but in a directory you don't expect, such as `C:\Windows\System32` where services run by default and where `LocalSystem` can write), or it throws and you ignore the exception. Create a [mre].

Comment: @CodeCaster: Or it throws and he catches the exception but has nowhere to write the details.

Comment: @JonathanWood: "Access to the file system" is not a binary privilege that some user accounts have and some don't.  Files are protected by "access control lists".  You must have at least read access to a whole bunch of system DLLs or your application wouldn't start.  You need to make sure that when you write your text file, you do so in a path whose ACL permits file creation and file write for the account in which your service runs.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, that's why I sort of assumed the process would be for me to create a service account and set the privileges I need. Currently, they are to write to files, read from files, copy files, delete files, and write to a zip file (if that's different than writing), all within the *My Documents* folder. Right now, it's working running under my admin account. But that doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: "within the My Documents folder".  Ahh, now we see the problem.  There is not just one "My Documents folder".  There is one (probably `C:\Users\X\Documents`) for each user profile X.  The "My Documents" folder for your developer login is not the "My Documents" folder of the service account.  Are you using hardcoded paths or e.g. `Environment.SpecialFolder` class?

Comment: @Ben that's why I asked the OP to provide a [mre] a couple of times already. It's almost their 800th question, they should know how this works by now.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Well you might actually be on to something there. I am running from Hangfire and it doesn't report any errors and I wasn't sure why. Maybe it did write it somewhere. That's an interesting clue there! Maybe I wrote it somewhere else. (I am using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)`.)

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/17426360/103167

Comment: @Jonathan suddenly there's Hangfire, a job scheduler... What job store do you use? Do your jobs log exceptions or run to completion? Does your service log anything anywhere else? As which user is your service running?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I checked all the visible *Documents* folders but don't see the file. How would one go about determining where that file is?

Comment: @CodeCaster: Yes, it logs to a log file. At least it tries to. But I can't debug it when it's running as a Windows service. And I can't find the file written.

Comment: One uses SysInternals' Procmon to see what paths a program is writing to, if one can't modify that program to log stuff in an accessible location.

Comment: @JonathanWood: If I know the filename but not the path, I turn to this amazing file system indexing tool `Everything`: https://www.voidtools.com/  Advertised to "Locate files and folders by name instantly" and it does.

Comment: You definitely can debug when running as a Windows Service, by running Visual Studio as administrator and attaching to the running process. Why don't you log the value of `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)`? You'll probably see it's something like `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Documents`. But what would I know.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Well you knew he had some sort of service wrapper, because console applications don't call SCM APIs or have a `ServiceMain` entrypoint.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Well, okay. I don't have VS on the server. I could log the value of `GetFolderPath()`, but if I can't find the file it writes it to, then how would I know what its value was?

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not denying that. OP has been claiming up and down that the service just does "nothing", while at the same time - and still - refusing to show any relevant code. Hangfire is a _job scheduler_ that runs tasks and handles exceptions.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Does voidtools find anything that Windows search cannot find? I did a Windows search of the drive and it didn't find the missing file.

Comment: @Jonathan then you change the log location to something like `C:\Temp\MyServiceLog.txt` to see whether that works...

Comment: @CodeCaster: Yes, I could do something like that.

Comment: @JonathanWood: Everything should be able to find files that Windows search running in your current user account can't see, because it uses admin rights to read the NTFS master file table.  You won't be able to *read* those files unless you elevate an editor, but you'll see them in the Everything search results.

Comment: You can use VS Remote Debugger if you want to debug from a different machine, and start *that* using Run As Admin. Anyway, if you would have just used full paths you wouldn't have had this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Windows Service created in .NET [typically looks like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service):

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundWorker>();
})
.UseWindowsService()
.Build();

host.Run();
```

Where `MyBackgroundWorker` is a `BackgroundService` that does its work in `ExecuteAsync()`. Or one can register various services that the host will run for you.

The `UseWindowsService()`, from [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices), makes the program tell Windows' Service Control Manager (SCM) that yes, this process is in fact hosting one Windows Service.

### The installation

Now when you deploy this service somewhere, say `C:\MyCoolService`, it has to be made known to the SCM. One usually uses `sc.exe` for this:

```
sc.exe create MyCoolService binPath= "C:\MyCoolService\MyCoolService.exe"
```

Not specifying a user account (using the `obj=`  argument) defaults to the built-in [LocalSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localsystem-account) account, which can do about everything on your machine. It can access any directory, it can represent the machine on the network, it is a bad default.

Anyhow, we now have a .NET application running as a Windows Service, blissfully running our `MyBackgroundWorker` implementation in the background.

### The permissions

There's nothing special about Windows Service users, apart from the built-in part of some of them. You could let your service run as `LocalSystem`, having access to about everything on your system, or you could let it run as a lesser-privileged account `LocalService`, which can access about nothing.

Or you could create a Windows (Active Directory or local) user and have your service run as that user. It can then access whatever that user can access, using Access Control Lists and whatnot.

### The problem

As you explained in comments, you use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` to obtain the path to write to. When running as `LocalSystem`, that returns an empty string, because the LocalSystem user does not have a My Documents folder. Who would read those documents anyway?

And what happens when you use that empty string to build a path to write files to? You write relative to the current directory.

What is the current directory for a Windows Service when not specified otherwise? `C:\Windows\system32`.  The `LocalSystem` user can and will happily write there.

That's where your files are.

Comment: This should not have taken 36 comments.

Comment: Yes, that's where the file is located (C:\Windows\system32). Thanks!

Comment: Don't run as _LocalSystem_.  If someone figures out how to compromise your service, they own your machine (think of LocalSystem like an admin account with a bit more juice).  Either grant LocalService rights to the portion of the file system you are interested in or use a dedicated account.  If the service is going to run on Windows Server or in Azure, then Windows has the concept of a Service Account - basically an account in which you can run your service that gets configured in Active Directory (and you don't need to manage passwords for it, the OS takes care of security)

Comment: @Flydog57: I'm on Windows but I'm not using Azure or Active Directory. When you say use a dedicated account, are you just talking about a new user account? Don't those have access to most of the file system too? If you know a link that elaborates in this, I'd definitely like to see it.